# The sequelize many-to-many setter does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to define a many-to-many relationship through Sequalize, but I can't seem to get the hang of applying the relationship after creating the elements.

The many-to-many relationship is between `LegalFoundation` and `Case`, and `LegalCase` has been defined in the DB, so it seems like `belongsToMany()` does its job.

However, after making sure that all of the `LegalFoundations` are defined, and the `Case` is created, I'm struggeling with defining the relationship between the two.

It seems like `created_case` is missing the required function: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: created_case.addLegalFoundation is not a fun n is not a function` . However, all the docs I've read show that the correct element should be returned by a `create` function. So I'm a bit stumped.

The GET-request returns `column legal_foundations->LegalCase.case_id does not exist` if thats any help in debugging.

Hope someone can show me the way!

#### database.js

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const database = new Sequelize('#####', '#####', '#####', {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op
})

const District = database.define('district', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false}
});

const LegalFoundation = database.define('legal_foundation', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    text: {type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: false}
});

const Case = database.define('case', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    ref: {type: Sequelize.TEXT},
    report: {type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)},
    consideration: {type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)},
    decision: {type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)},
    date: {type: Sequelize.DATE}
});

District.hasMany(Case)
LegalFoundation.belongsToMany(Case, {through: 'LegalCase', as: 'cases', foreignKey: "case_id"})
Case.belongsToMany(LegalFoundation, {through: 'LegalCase', as: 'legal_foundations', foreignKey: "legal_foundation_id"})

module.exports = {
    database,
    District,
    LegalFoundation,
    Case
}
```

#### case.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const { Case, District, LegalFoundation } = require('./db/database')
const { Op, Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {ref, report, consideration, decision, legal_foundation, date, district} = req.body;
        const [district_ins, created_d] = await District.findOrCreate({
            where: {
                name: district
            },
        });
        foundations = [];
        if (typeof legal_foundation == 'object'){
            legal_foundation.forEach(async element => {
                let [f, created_f] = await LegalFoundation.findOrCreate({
                    where: {
                        text: element
                    }
                });
                foundations.push(f.id)
            });
        } else {
            let [f, created_f] = await LegalFoundation.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    text: legal_foundation
                }
            });
            foundations.push(f.id)
        }
        const created_case = await Case.create({
            ref: ref,
            report: report,
            consideration: consideration,
            decision: decision,
            date: date,
            districtId: district_ins.id
        });

        foundations.forEach(async element => {
            await created_case.addLegalFoundation(element);
        });

        res.json({success: true, id})
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.json({success: false, error: error})
    }
})

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const all = await Case.findAll({include: {
            model: LegalFoundation,
            as: 'legal_foundations'
        }});
        res.json({success: true, item: all});
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.json({success: false, error: error.message})
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems here:

1. Incorrect `belongsToMany` associations. `foreignKey` should indicate to a field of a model whose method `belongsToMany` you call:

```js
LegalFoundation.belongsToMany(Case, {through: 'LegalCase', as: 'cases',
  foreignKey: "legal_foundation_id", otherKey: "case_id" })
Case.belongsToMany(LegalFoundation, {through: 'LegalCase', as: 'legal_foundations', 
  foreignKey: "case_id", otherKey: "legal_foundation_id"})
```

2. `forEach` method cannot wait for async iterations. You should use `for of`:

```
for (const element of legal_foundation) {
  let [f, created_f] = await LegalFoundation.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      text: element
    }
  });
  foundations.push(f.id)
}
```

```js
for (const element of foundations) {
  await created_case.addLegalFoundation(element);
}
```

3. I suppose because you used `legal_foundations` name with `_` then try to look at methods of `created_case` maybe they should be like `addLegal_Foundation` or `addLegal_foundation`

Comment: Fantastic, all of these solved it (including `addLegal_foundation`). Thanks for helping out, I'll remember the `forEach`-issue.